# Is it possible to find COUNT function and then to show only certain values that are higher than 10

Tags: mysql, mariadb

for example:

```
SELECT doctor.name
     , doctor.surname
     , COUNT(checkup.doctor) 
  FROM doctor
     , checkup 
 WHERE doctor.id = checkup.doctor 
 GROUP 
    BY doctor.name  
 ORDER 
    BY checkup.doctor
```

this gives me  list of all doctor that had checkup with patients, but i want to show only doctor with  number of checkup more than 10 what to add to my sql

Comment: surname is meaningless in this result set.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MariaDB? You tagged both and they are quite similar, but still different products with different sets of features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to limit your result rows according to an aggregation result. You'd do that in the `HAVING` clause.

As to your query: What is `name`? A unique name for every doctor? Otherwise better group by the ID - only then is this query valid according to the SQL standard. Then you are using a join syntax that we stopped using in the 1990s. Please use proper ANSI joins instead.

I prefer aggregating before joining, but that's just personal preference:

```
select d.name, d.surname, c.checkups
from doctor
join 
(
  select doctor as doctor_id, count(*) as checkups
  from checkup 
  group by doctor
  having count(*) > 10
) c on c.doctor_id = d.id
order by d.id;
```

You could just as well use

```
select d.name, d.surname, count(*) as checkups
from doctor d
join checkup c on c.doctor = d.id
group by d.id
having count(*) > 10
order by d.id;
```

Comment: i do agree that name can not be unique,but  in this case, i didn't have any repeating name, so i could manage without grouping by ID.But thank you for showing me the best standardise way of quering this specific case.This will help me in future.

Comment: @Pera It seems odd to exclde someone from the group in the future because they have the same name as someone else already within the group.

Comment: @Strawberry I had to task to find the doctors who up until now had more than 10.So i am not excluding anyone.But as i said previously, it is better to group by id and to show firstly id, because of  possibility f having more than one people with smae namae and even surname.

Comment: @Strawberry and this is university task one of many for project from databases.so this is not real life.So don't think that this will affect anything.This is imaginary system.

Comment: But the way you think about real data and imaginary data should be the same

Comment: @Strawberry yes, but it won't make some damage if i it isn't in real life and in real information system.

Answer (score 0):

Do the fact you are using aggregation function as count If you want only the result with more then 10 COUNT(checkup.doctor)

you could filter the result using having

```
SELECT doctor.name,doctor.surname,COUNT(checkup.doctor) 
FROM doctor
INNER JOIN  checkup  doctor.id=checkup.doctor 
GROUP BY doctor.name  
Having  COUNT(checkup.doctor) > 10 
ORDER BY COUNT(checkup.doctor)
```

the where clause work on the selecting row so don't know the result of an aggregated  result  .. for this SQL use the  having clause that filter  the result of a select

Comment: Thanks.This worked :) i will accept your grreat answer

Comment: @Pera We have very different definitions of 'worked'!!

Comment: @Strawberry  well it showed me only the doctor with more than 10 checkups.That worked for me

Comment: @scaisEdge i didn't downwoted. i still can not vote i do not have enough reputatin to vote as stackoverflow said.

Comment: @Pera  i know .. don't worry  .. the importantb is that my answer helped  you at solve your problem .. a

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** You can use `HAVING` clause to filter out the aggregation result and try to avoid outdated joins. `Surname` doesn't meaning there in `GROUP BY` so you use `MAX` to pick in select and remove from `GROUP BY` or leave as it is:

```
SELECT doctor.name
    , doctor.surname
    , COUNT(checkup.doctor) 
FROM doctor
INNER JOIN checkup ON doctor.id = checkup.doctor 
GROUP BY doctor.name, doctor.surname
HAVING COUNT(checkup.doctor) > 10
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work for you:

```
SELECT 
  doctor.name, doctor.surname, checkup_stat.checkup_count 
FROM 
  (SELECT doctor, COUNT(1) AS checkup_count FROM checkup GROUP BY doctor ORDER BY doctor) AS checkup_stat 
RIGHT JOIN 
  doctor 
ON 
  doctor.id = checkup_stat.doctor 
WHERE 
  checkup_stat.checkup_count > 10;
```

- Firstly, use a subquery to get the checkup count for every doctor.
- Secondly, select the records from the subquery result where checkup count > 10.
- Then, just join them together.

Comment: Right joins are considered less readable than left joins, so avoid them and use left outer joins instead. In this case no outer join is needed, so you shouldn't apply one. Your `WHERE` clause even renders the outer join an inner join, because in outer-joined rows `checkup_stat.checkup_count` will be null and thus dismissed again. The `ON` clause is wrong; it should be `ON doctor.id = checkup_stat.doctor`. `COUNT(1)` should be `COUNT(*)` as you merely want to count rows (`COUNT(1)` is supposed to count all rows for which a generated 1 would be not null - same result but weird approach).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you!